# Local server for Dash does not display app

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

When i execute my code in jupyter notebook to start my dash app, it gives me an error message and doesn't display what I want it to.

**Code:**

`import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html`

`app = dash.Dash()`

`app.layout = html.Div('Dash tutorials')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run_server(debug=True)`

**The output:**

Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

Debugger PIN: 354-007-338

- Serving Flask app "**main**" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production

  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.

  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

**The image that get displayed at http://127.0.0.1:8050/ :**

[Image of the http address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogw8Z.png)

Comment: Can you share the full traceback here as well?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what that is. I've been looking online to understand what a trackback is, but I'm not sure if my code is outputting that.

Comment: That's the full path through the code that caused the error. Your notebook is telling you how to see more, `use %tb to see the full traceback`.